# What is Prince Pondicherry’s wife called in Charlie and the Chocolate Factory?

Tags: character-identification, names, charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory

In Charlie and the Chocolate Factory, Grandpa Joe tells Charlie the story of Prince Pondicherry and the palace he got that was made of chocolate.

His Princess went unnamed and the 2005 film adaptation says that her name is “PRINCESS Pondicherry.”

Is there any canon proof what her name is? Like in the credits of the 2005 film or anywhere

Comment: Is there even a cannon name for the Prince?

Comment: The name of a character who is on-screen for ten seconds, has no dialogue, and contributes nothing to the plot cannot *possibly* be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [credits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0367594/fullcredits), they're listed as Prince and Princess Pondicherry. I think we can reasonably assume that they do have names, but they're not disclosed in the film (for which she was created) or the source novel which only mentions the prince.

[image]